# Broken images on the front-end when uploaded through WYSIWYG or Widgets

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, media-images

Is anyone else experiencing broken imagery on the front-end when uploading the image through WYSIWYG or widgets via the media gallery.

We find that the image shows for a short period on the front-end but it eventually disappears and renders a broken image tag on the front-end.

It looks like it's a core Magento error which has been documented [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6138), in this example its related to the product description attribute but it does occur elsewhere e.g in widgets.

Is there a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: which version are you using v2.0.x or v2.1.x specify it fully as this have been fixed in future releases.

Comment: hey @userpk I am using v2.1.5, which release has it been fixed on?